# JavaFx: TreeTableView arrow reference

Tags: java, css, javafx, treeview, javafx-8

How can I get a reference to the expand/collapse "arrow" in a TreeTableView?

I cannot provide any code, since, I didn't really know what to look for.

Here is an image that shows what I need. The highlighted arrows are which I need.

I want to remove it, while keeping the collapse/expand mechanism(which works also if I click on the row itself), or making it transparent via css.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background of the arrow to transparent via CSS stylesheet. The CSS below contains code for both `TreeTableView` and `TreeView`, since you write about `TreeTableView` but your screenshot shows a `TreeView`:

```css
.tree-cell .arrow,
.tree-table-row-cell .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, I was too lazy to create another mock for a `TreeTableView` and I just used an old TreeView to show what I need :)

Comment: I've found that a `TreeCell` has a `disclosureNode()` property while, a TreeTableCell hasn't. There I could manipulate relative easy, using that reference, but at TTC it is not so easy, Or did I miss something?

Comment: It works indeed, but do you know if I can get a reference to the node like I can in a simple `TreeView`?